# Add silence to wav file at specific time using ffmpeg

Tags: c#, audio, ffmpeg

I have an audio (.wav) file . i want to add silence at specific time 
For example 
i have an audio (.wav) file of 60 sec duration i want to insert silence at 14th sec to 18th second which overlay the current audio not increase the duration.
I am looking for a FFMPEG command for this .. but not any luck yet .

Comment: I'm fairly certain I didn't flag this as a dupe, but for migration to Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -af volume=0:enable='between(t,14,18)' out.wav
```

---

To insert silence,

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -filter_complex "anullsrc,atrim=0:4[s];[0]atrim=0:14[a];[0]atrim=14,asetpts=N/SR/TB[b];[a][s][b]concat=3:v=0:a=1" out.wav
```

Comment: what if i dont want to overlay ? like what if i want to insert silence no matter if the duration get increases. can i do this without using another file with silence

Comment: The command yor provided at first and the command you have provided secondly are giving the same result . they are muting the volume for the given duration .

Comment: See corrected cmd.

Comment: Man its working like a Gem. Thanks
Can you please define it little bit that what u did here . I want to add multiple silence